# jQuery position not returning relative value?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to comprehend jQuery's position() function. The documentation states that this returns the element's position relative to its parent:

*Description: Get the current coordinates of the first element in the set of matched elements, relative to the offset parent.*

So, when I call position() on the first div inside a parent div, I expect to get 0,0.
Instead, I get the absolute position of the parent. How is this possible?
And how do I get the relative position of the first div inside another div?

My code:

```
<div id="icons">
    <div class="icon" id="icon0"></div>
    <div class="icon" id="icon1"></div>
    <div class="icon" id="icon2"></div>
</div>
```

Now I need the relative position of the first icon:

```
console.log("icon 0 position: " + $("#icon0").position().left + " " + $("#icon0").position().top);
```

This returns the position of the "#icons" div instead of 0,0.

Comment: What is the css for this?

Comment: set #icons `position` to `relative` or `absolute`. Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/PVM2a/1/

Comment: Please add the css for your elements, because if the parent is absolutely positioned then the result is 0,0 http://jsfiddle.net/PVM2a/2/ We cannot determine where the issue is if you do not provide the css or setup a fiddle or your own

Comment: As [the documentation says](http://api.jquery.com/position/), `.position()` returns the position relative to the nearest `absolute` (or `fixed`, or any non-relative) parent element: http://jsfiddle.net/A5Byv/ Attach your css so we can see if it is indeed unexpected behaviour.

Comment: The documentation says "the offset parent" - not clearly explaining what an offset parent is - hence the confusion. Thanks! It's working now.

Answer (score 0):

try using offset() instead of position()

```
$("#icon0").offset()
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead).